# avr-gcc can't find avr/io.h

Tags: arch-linux

I want to compile Xmega_bootloader

but when I start make I get this error:

```
[arkadi@arkadi-linux /home/arkadi/Xmega_Bootloader $]make
avr-gcc  -mmcu=atxmega64a3u -Wall -gdwarf-2 -std=gnu99 -DF_CPU=2000000UL -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -DBOOT_PAGE_SIZE=256 -DAPP_PAGE_SIZE=256 -DMCU=atxmega64a3u -DBAUD_RATE=115200 -DMY_UART=C,0 -DENTER_BOOTLOADER_PIN=B,2 -DLED_PIN=D,2 -DLED_ON=0 -DBOOTLOADER_PIN_EN=0 -MD -MP -MT sp_driver.o -x assembler-with-cpp -Wa,-gdwarf2 -c  sp_driver.s
sp_driver.s:69:20: fatal error: avr\io.h: No such file or directory
 #include <avr\io.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:374: recipe for target 'sp_driver.o' failed
make: *** [sp_driver.o] Error 1
```

I'm running on

```
Linux arkadi-linux 4.0.7-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 30 07:50:21 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and I have installed avr-gcc and avr-libc.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I used '\' in the code.

In linux it must be '/' ,
so to make the code portable the line must be:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
```